# Function to receive scheme data from other app not triggering

Tags: swift, xcode

I am using scheme in my app to pass data from a second app to my app.
I am already able to open my app using it's scheme from second app.
But now I will like to parse the URL data that was sent from the second app. I found a tutorial online about implementing a method as seen below in my viewController class but this method is never triggered. Do i need to place it somewhere specific ? right now it's just in the viewController class.

I just started coding in Swift this week to create a POC, I have more of an Android background.

```
func application(app: UIApplication,
                     open url: URL,
                     options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:] ) -> Bool {

        // Determine who sent the URL.
        let sendingAppID = options[.sourceApplication]
        print("source application = \(sendingAppID ?? "Unknown")")

        // Process the URL.
        guard let components = NSURLComponents(url: url, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: true),
          //  let ro_response = components.path,
            let params = components.queryItems else {
                print("Invalid")
                return false
        }

        if let serial = params.first(where: { $0.name == "serial" })?.value {
            self.SERIAL = serial as String


        } else {
            return false;

        }

        if let otp = params.first(where: { $0.name == "otp" })?.value {
            self.OTP = otp as String

        } else {
            return false;

        }
        return true

    }
```

Comment: Make sure your url query items are percent encoded.

Answer (score 0):

This is a method from `UIApplicationDelegate` so you have to implement it in your `AppDelegate`.

Comment: Hello @Gaël, I copied the code to my AppDelegate class and still not getting triggered after the app opens.

Comment: Did you also add your `URL Schemes` in your `Info.plist` using `CFBundleURLSchemes`?